# Is using a WebServer for executing methods remotely a good architectural decision?

Tags: json, performance, jboss, webserver, load-balancing

**A very small explanation of what i am talking about is presented below.**

- In my organization a strange kind of effort for load distributing is
  implemented, i will attempt to explain it below.
- A JBoss server runs in a machine with some IP xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx
- There is an app which has many heavy time & resource consuming work
  to do (heavy in terms of I/O operation ex- Large file uploads &
  downloads - in Gigabytes)
- Methods written in a Rest WebApp accessible by the URLs & parameters
  to methods passed as URL params, set to the type POST, return value
  of the methods as JSON output.
- The App in question has a framework written just to make post calls
  to the aforementioned WebApp wrapped nicely so that the calls can be
  made without the programmer knowing what happens in the background.
- This framework has externalized parameters which takes in the IP of
  the machines running the WebApps and configure a list of such
  machines available & route the method calls to the one least busy
  whenever a method call to the framework is made.

Everything looks good but i suspect wrapping things in a http websever & doing processing there & sending the outputs in json may slow down things & collecting the logs in case of failures maybe tough.

**Questions**

I want to know the views of other programmers on this & whether this is a nice approach or not.

Also do any existing commercial applications follow something similar while trying to distribute the load?

Answer (score 1):

In my opinion, the efficiency of load balancing lies in the tricky process of choosing the right node that will process your request.

A usual approach can be to monitor the CPU usage of the nodes that have to take the load and send the load to the one least busy. This process should be both accurate and efficient.

In your case, wrapping up of request and transfer of Json data should be a thing of least concern as they seem to be required activities and light ones too. Focus should be on the load balancing activity.

**Answer to comment**

If I understood correctly, http methodserver are there to process the requests from the central app. Load balancing will not be done by them. There has to be a central load balancing mechanism/tool that has to decide which methodserver will take which request.

All the methodservers (slaves) should be identical. That reduces maintainability effort as a fix can be done on one node and can be propagated to other nodes. This is how it is done in my organization.

It may be a requirement if a similar operation is done repeatedly, application server may reduce some duplicity here.

Comment: So in other words this concept of creating http methodservers to balance the load is fine ? I understand that they might be very low in load as compared to the real file upload/download & other IO query operations but don't you think if these methods are called very very frequently to perform some operation which isn't that heavy can put an major impact on the performance ? What about some other aspects such as maintainability of such a system?

Comment: I edited my answer to include my replies to your comment.